# Rake aborted. Devise.secret_key was not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake

Rake aborted when I do `rake db:migrate`.

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. 
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by that by that?

Comment: read the link he provided